# Python Pandas: Vectorized Way of Cleaning Buy and Sell Signals

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I'm trying to simulate financial trades using a **vectorized** approach in python. Part of this includes removing duplicate signals.

To elaborate, I've developed a `buy_signal` column and a `sell_signal` column. These columns contain booleans in the form of 1s and 0s.

Looking at the signals from the top-down, I don't want to trigger a second `buy_signal` before a `sell_signal` triggers, AKA if a 'position' is open. Same thing with sell signals, I do not want duplicate sell signals if a 'position' is closed. If a `sell_signal` and `buy_signal` are `1`, set them both to 0.

What is the best way to remove these irrelevant signals?

Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "buy_signal": [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        "sell_signal": [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    }
)
print(df)
```

```
   buy_signal  sell_signal
0           1            0
1           1            0
2           1            1
3           1            1
4           0            1
5           0            0
6           1            0
7           1            0
8           1            1
9           0            0
```

Here's the result I want:

```
   buy_signal  sell_signal
0           1            0
1           0            0
2           0            1
3           0            0
4           0            0
5           0            0
6           1            0
7           0            0
8           0            1
9           0            0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said earlier (in a comment about a response since then deleted), one **must consider** the interaction between buy and sell signals, and cannot simply operate on each independently.

The key idea is to consider a quantity `q` (or "position") that is the amount currently held, and that the OP says would like bounded to `[0, 1]`. That quantity is `cumsum(buy - sell)` after cleaning.

Therefore, the problem reduces to "cumulative sum with limits", which unfortunately cannot be done in a vectorized way with `numpy` or `pandas`, but that we can code quite efficiently using `numba`. The code below processes 1 million rows in 37 ms.

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def cumsum_clip(a, xmin=-np.inf, xmax=np.inf):
    res = np.empty_like(a)
    c = 0
    for i in range(len(a)):
        c = min(max(c + a[i], xmin), xmax)
        res[i] = c
    return res


def clean_buy_sell(df, xmin=0, xmax=1):
    # model the quantity held: cumulative sum of buy-sell clipped in
    # [xmin, xmax]
    # note that, when buy and sell are equal, there is no change
    q = cumsum_clip(
        (df['buy_signal'] - df['sell_signal']).values,
        xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax)

    # derive actual transactions: positive for buy, negative for sell, 0 for hold
    trans = np.diff(np.r_[0, q])
    df = df.assign(
        buy_signal=np.clip(trans, 0, None),
        sell_signal=np.clip(-trans, 0, None),
    )
    
    return df
```

Now:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "buy_signal": [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        "sell_signal": [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    }
)
new_df = clean_buy_sell(df)

>>> new_df
   buy_signal  sell_signal
0           1            0
1           0            0
2           0            0
3           0            0
4           0            1
5           0            0
6           1            0
7           0            0
8           0            0
9           0            0
```

#### Speed and correctness

```py
n = 1_000_000

np.random.seed(0)  # repeatable example
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0, 1], (n, 2)),
                  columns=['buy_signal', 'sell_signal'])

%timeit clean_buy_sell(df)
37.3 ms ± 104 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Correctness tests:

```py
z = clean_buy_sell(df)
q = (z['buy_signal'] - z['sell_signal']).cumsum()

# q is quantity held through time; must be in {0, 1}
assert q.isin({0, 1}).all()

# we should not have introduced any new buy signal:
# check that any buy == 1 in z was also 1 in df

assert not (z['buy_signal'] & ~df['buy_signal']).any()

# same for sell signal:
assert not (z['sell_signal'] & ~df['sell_signal']).any()

# finally, buy and sell should never be 1 on the same row:
assert not (z['buy_signal'] & z['sell_signal']).any()
```

#### Bonus: other limits, fractional buys and sells

For fun, we can consider the more general case where buy and sell values are fractional (or any float value), and the limits are not `[0, 1]`. There is nothing to change to the current version of `clean_buy_sell`, which is general enough to handle these conditions.

```py
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.uniform(0, 1, (100, 2)),
    columns=['buy_signal', 'sell_signal'],
)

# set limits to -1, 2: we can sell short (borrow) up to 1 unit
# and own up to 2 units.
z = clean_buy_sell(df, -1, 2)

(z['buy_signal'] - z['sell_signal']).cumsum().plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response. the Module VectorBT utilizes numba to accomplish this as well. I was hoping to come up with a way to implement this exclusively in pandas, but it seems like numba is the way to go!

Comment: That's some really detailed answer, thank you for this! Do you have an idea on how one could tackle some extra steps like adding take profit and stop loss into the selling signal based on the clean buy signals and then apply the cleaning again? I guess it would still be done using numba, is there an easier vectorial method?